# Architecture of SaaS Web Application With AWS lambda Using Java or Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I have developed multiple microServices in my previous projects, So am well versed on it. Currently we are on the edge to start developing a SaaS webApp using java or springboot & we want to leverage AWS lambda for pricing sake but couple things I couldn't understand and couldn't find good example are:

1. Is it feasible to develop web app fully on AWS lambda using JAVA or springboot?(I
   know we can write java function on lambda).
2. How do we tackle code reusability on AWS Lambda?
3. If we end up having 100 lambda functions, does it mean we need to build
   100 jar's for each function?
4. Does each end point need to be represent by single lambda function?

I would really appreciate it if you can attache a link for similar scenario!!!

Comment: 1. yes, and you can have a SpringBoot lambda but warm up times are slow
2. You cn build a lmbda using mvn or gradle with dependencies as you build any other java
3. you can have 100 handlers in one jar and deploy that one jar 100 times, but loose the chance of really seeing the value of single responsiblity in a lambda. Build the small 100...
4. Bigger qustion than you think. A lambda is just a function. You can do anything in it, for instance place a message on Eventbridge and die, but the EB message could spawn 1000 different lambdas!

Comment: From experience I can say that having each endpoint in a separate lambda really is no fun. It is not fun to set up the dependencies, it is not fun to deploy, it is not fun to debug.